# calling a java object in the stored procedure as an argument

Tags: java

I wanted to know whether we can pass a java object inside the stored procedure call as an argument. Here is my java code where i have used the stored procedure call. Please help me in finding the solution for this

```
public void addPatientInfo(PatientInfo patientInfo) throws SQLException
{   
    CallableStatement cst = null;

    try {
        logger.info("Enter addPatientInfo");
        dbConnection = DbConnectionImpl.getDbConnection(dbConnInfo);
        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
        cst = dbConnection.prepareCall("{ call add_patient(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }");

        cst.setInt(1, patientInfo.getSalutationType().getSalutationTypeId());
        cst.setString(2, patientInfo.getFirstName());
        cst.setString(3, patientInfo.getMiddleName());
        cst.setString(4, patientInfo.getLastName());
        cst.setString(5, patientInfo.getGender());
        cst.setString(6, patientInfo.getDob());
        cst.setString(7, patientInfo.getOccupation());
        cst.setInt(8, ApplicationConstants.OWNER_TYPE_PATIENT);
        cst.setString(9, patientInfo.getEducation());
        cst.setString(10,patientInfo.getPatientIdentityNo());

        cst.execute();
        dbConnection.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any method where i can pass patientInfo inside the add_patient stored procedure call as an arguement?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking if you can do this:

```
cst = dbConnection.prepareCall("{ call add_patient(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }");
cst.setObject(1, patientInfo);
```

In the sense of getting the prepared statement to know what properties to assign to what database fields, then the answer is no.

There is actually a setObject() on the PreparedStatement class though. But it is focused on a specific range of acceptable classes which produce specific output. Java beans are not in that list.

Comment: nope. I wanted to know whether we can pass patientInfo like call add_patient(patientInfo) where i can get all the arguements from the database.Is this a right technique.Or is there any method to do such a thing

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are saying...

There's a way,
but for that you'll have to [create an object in Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/files/advanced/ObjectJavaSample/Readme.html), and map it to Java Object.